# Support for DatagramSocket (UDP)?

Tags: codenameone

My app requires minimal support for DatagramSocket (i.e. UDP).

Specifically, I need new DatagramSocket(), send(DatagramPacket p) and receive(DatagramPacket p).  I'd like to support both iOS and Android.

My app works in the simulator, but I found this in the documentation: "At this moment Codename One only supports TCP sockets."

Is this likely to change anytime soon?  Or will I have to dive into native code to accomplish what I need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it works in the simulator I guess you used the `java.net` API's which aren't supported. You can [read this](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/why-we-dont-support-the-full-java-api.html) to understand why some API's including the `java.net` API's aren't supported.

You can use native interfaces to wrap native socket implementations for portability currently there are two such cn1libs but they focus on TCP sockets:
https://github.com/shannah/CN1Sockets and https://github.com/shannah/cn1-websockets

You can write a similar API targeting Datagram. To learn more about native interfaces see https://www.codenameone.com/how-do-i---access-native-device-functionality-invoke-native-interfaces.html

Comment: Yes, I used java.net APIs in the simulator for testing.  I need UDP so TCP support is not useful.  I guess I'll be looking into native code libraries.